# anchor tag working on Firefox and not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, anchor

I am trying to use anchor tag on 2 pages.
On the first page I have this link:

```
<p><a href="/analog.html#boris">Topic 2</a></p>
```

And on the second page I have this anchor tag:

```
<h2 id="boris">Boris</h2>
```

If I click on the link on the first page and use Firefox it goes to the second page and anchor works fine, meaning top of the page will be at `Boris`. However doing the same thing on Chrome does not work.

here is a link to the [first page](http://www.doradolist.com/boris-murmann.html). At the bottom of the first page you can click on `Topic 2` to go to the second page with anchor tag.

Why it works on Firefox but not on Chrome and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you edit both pages?

Comment: Yes I can edit them, why?

Comment: To know if we are looking for a solution from page1 only, from page2 only or maybe from both. Now, fast looking at your second page, what are these `<div1>` and `<myframe>` elements? Seems there is nothing declaring custom elements there (though I may have missed it), and that it would anyway be invalid names for CE (though I'm not a ninja in this field)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you look at the second page you can see that I have: <h2 id="boris">Boris</h2>. why <div1> and <myframe> matters?

Comment: Could be because if the browser doesn't know how to render it at the time it reaches it's scrollToAnchor code, these elements may very well have 0 height and thus `#Boris` is at the top, until the browser finally realize it has to set some size, and push all the content down, but it happens after it's scrolled. However that's just suppositions from my side. It could come from other things, like the fact you do lazy-load your images or something else. Would be great if you could set up a [mcve], for instance http://plnkr.co/edit/ may help demonstrating multi-docs issues in a minimal way.

Comment: Here is the plnkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/x3B6v9qTAM4bWOiGlBeE

Comment: Does this reproduce the problem for you? Doesn't for me (#boris)  is not down enough to be visibly scrolled to, and even when this is fixed, it actually work well.

Comment: It looks like it works partially. Why it doesn't bring Boris to the top of the page? (on Firefox it bring Boris to the top of the page).  But even this doesn't happen on my website. Do you think it is due to a JS code that I am using or something like that? If this is related to JS what could be the solution?